# Find out when cursor is moved (UITextView)

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a UITextView that has its delegate set to my view controller

I would like to your help in figuring out how to find out, through delegate methods, subclassing, selectors and what not, when the cursor is moved.

I've tried `-textViewDidChange` and `-textViewDidChangeSelection` among all other delegate methods but they don't get called when the cursor was moved within the textview...

So how can I discover when the caret is moved in my `UITextView` and act upon it as necessary(run some code)

This may seem like an unpractical question but I have a scenario where I need to update a label when the cursor is moved up or down so I would like to fig

Thanks, I hope I've been as clear as possible

Comment: The `textViewDidChangeSelection:` `UITextView` delegate method is the correct one to use. If it isn't being called then you haven't set the text view's `delegate` property properly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just to expand on @rmaddy's comment. You'll want to use the `UITextViewDelegate` method [-textViewDidChangeSelection:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewDidChangeSelection%3a) to be notified when the selected range in the text view changes. From there, you can access the [NSRange](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSMakeRange) representing the selection of text via the text view's `selectedRange` property.

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSRange range = textView.selectedRange;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

```
func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.othersTextView.selectedRange = NSRange(location: 0,length: 0)
    }
}
```

Setting the cursor always to the beginning of the UITextView